# jps does not show hmaster but <no information available>

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I configured HBase today and I configured it correctly at first. However, when I ran HBase use the code 'start-all.sh' again, I could not see 'Hmaster' anywhere. It just shows like:

```
[root@master bin]# jps
25164 QuorumPeerMain
83447 HRegionServer
44542 NameNode
44789 DataNode
45098 SecondaryNameNode
45378 ResourceManager
45536 NodeManager
56678 <no information available>
56949 Jps
```

when I 'jps' again, '':
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuaHM.png)
and the log shows:

```
[root@master bin]# cd /home/hadoop/hbase-2.2.3/logs
[root@master logs]# ls
hbase-root-master-master.log        hbase-root-regionserver-master.out.1
hbase-root-master-master.out        hbase-root-regionserver-master.out.2
hbase-root-master-master.out.1      hbase-root-regionserver-master.out.3
hbase-root-regionserver-master.log  hbase-root-regionserver-master.out.4
hbase-root-regionserver-master.out  SecurityAuth.audit
[root@master logs]# tail hbase-root-master-master.log
2022-04-28 17:29:56,674 INFO  [master/master:16000] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x100000e4a0d0020 closed
2022-04-28 17:29:56,674 INFO  [master/master:16000] regionserver.HRegionServer: Exiting; stopping=master,16000,1651138191876; zookeeper connection closed.
2022-04-28 17:29:56,674 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down for session: 0x100000e4a0d0020
2022-04-28 17:29:56,674 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: HMaster Aborted
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:244)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2940)
[root@master logs]#
```

Comment: Zookeeper isn't running either, which Hbase needs

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by adding the following configuration to the configuration file "hbase-site.xml":

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

I do not why, but it works.